# Difference between isSuccessful() and isComplete() method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase in my android application.In my sign-up method I'm using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method.To check if my sign up process is successful or not I'm using `isSuccessful()` method.

```
 firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(m,p).addOnCompleteListener(new 
 OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() 
 {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
             {
                //some message               
             }
            else
            {
                 //some other message
            }
  };
```

But every time I try to sign up,the message shows that it hasn't been successful. Then I use `isComplete()` instead of `isSuccessful()` and then it worked fine.I also checked the Firebase dashboard to ensure if the sign up process is working fine and it is.
Now I want to know if there is any major difference between these two methods and if there will be any further problem if I use `isComplete()`,because I have checked other tutorials where `isSuccessful()` has been used.
One more thing,for the same code `isComplete()` is returning true and creating user but `isSuccessful()` isn't.
The complete code:

```
 public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText mail,pass,cPass;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private ImageButton reg;
private TextView warn;
private String a,b,c;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    mail=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    pass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
    cPass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Cpass);
    reg=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reg);
    firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
    warn=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.warnTv);
    warn.setText("");
    reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            a=mail.getText().toString().trim();
            b=pass.getText().toString().trim();
            c=cPass.getText().toString().trim();
            if(a.isEmpty() || b.isEmpty() || c.isEmpty())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"all the fields are mandatory",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                if(LoginActivity.validate(a))
                {
                    if(b.equals(c))
                    {
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Wait a sec");
                        progressDialog.show();
                        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(a,b).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful())
                                {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registration successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        
                        warn.setText("Passwords in both the field must be same");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    warn.setText("Enter a valid emailId");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Please help me with its answer.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not only the difference between these two methods I also want to know why  (or what are the possible reasons for)the 'isSuccessful()' method isn't returning true?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A Task is "complete" when the work represented by the Task is finished, regardless of its success or failure.  There may or may not have been an error, and you have to check for that.

A Task is "successful" when the work represented by the task is finished, as expected, with no errors.

Comment: Well elaborate.

Comment: When the task is successful? 'isComplete()' is returning true when the user and password has been added successfully but 'isSuccessful()' isn't.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you're referring to that doesn't work the way you expect.  Right now, your code is only showing an onComplete listener that checks for success.

Comment: Are there cases where the code contained within a OnFailureListener is executed after a OnCompleteListener? Tks

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Google Play services version 9.0.0, you can use a **Task API** and a number of methods that return Task e.g. fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation. Task is an API that represents asynchronous method calls, similar to PendingResult in previous versions of Google Play Services.

**Handling task results**

***To be notified when the task succeeds, attach an *OnSuccessListener****

```
task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
    // Task completed successfully
    // ...
}});
```

***To be notified when the task fails, attach an *OnFailureListener*:***

```
task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        // Task failed with an exception
        // ...
    }
});
```

***To handle success and failure in the same listener, attach an OnCompleteListener:***

```
task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // Task completed successfully
            AuthResult result = task.getResult();
        } else {
            // Task failed with an exception
            Exception exception = task.getException();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What happens when the task is cancelled? Is the failure listener called?

Answer (score 0):

`isComplete()`

Returns true if the Task is complete; false otherwise.

`isSuccessful()`

Returns true if the Task has completed successfully; false otherwise.